# Is it possible to construct a StructOpt Args object without parsing command line params for testing?

Tags: rust, structopt

I have a fn main that is parsing arguments via StructOpt .. Args::from_args.

Is there a way to create this Args object without actually starting the executable for testing? Can I just create a Args object directly?

Can I do this for example

```
fn test_function() {
    let args = Args::default();
    args.param1 = "value1";
    args.param2 = "value2";

    core_function(args);
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::from_args();
    core_function(args);
}
```

Comment: Is `Args` an external type? Typically you define your own struct and just `#[derive(StructOpt)]`  on it, meaning you can initialize it any way you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, structopt also provides [`from_iter` and `from_iter_safe`](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.15/structopt/trait.StructOpt.html#method.from_iter) which do what you'd expect: they take iterables of strings, and parse those as if they were CLI args.

All of them really delegate to clap, but semantically `from_args` just calls `from_iter` with `args_os()` as parameter.

`from_iter_safe` is probably the one you want to use in a test: much like `from_args`, `from_iter` will print an error message and immediately exit if a parsing / matching error occurs.